# is it safe for a coroutine generator to iterate over a string_view?

Tags: c++, coroutine, string-view

I am starting with c++ coroutines and I have an implementation of a generator. It works fine, but I am worried about lifetimes. Specifically I saw warnings about not using captures in lambdas for coroutines because at the first suspension point the lambda will be destroyed and the captured data will not exist anymore. Also C++ guidelines:"CP.53: Parameters to coroutines should not be passed by reference". What about this code:

```
std::string get_string();

MyGenerator<char> iterate_string(std::string_view sv)
{
   for (auto c : sv)
      co_yield c;
}

void do_something()
{
   for (auto c : iterate_string(get_string())
      std::cout << c;
}
```

I am passing (well, creating) a value of string_view; but that in itself is only a reference to a temporary std::string.

Is "iterate_string" safe? I think it is, the ranged for-loop is responsible for the lifetime; but I also wouldn't have expected problems using captures in a lambda coroutine.

Comment: Looks like UB until C++23 to me. [P2718R0](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2718r0.html) fixes this, but [no compiler implements it yet](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support).

Comment: I did some tests on Apple clang; it is not safe, the string gets destructed before iterate_string even starts.